# Bad MVVM practice? (CommandParameter)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, parameters, command

In my code I have 3 buttons. Each of them execute something different. I have let them execute using the same command but I gave them different CommandParameter's to specify the difference.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about

**XAML:**

```
            <Button Command="{Binding UpdateCommand}" CommandParameter="Add">Add Client</Button> 
            <Button Command="{Binding UpdateCommand}" CommandParameter="Change">Change Client</Button>
            <Button Command="{Binding UpdateCommand}" CommandParameter="Remove">Remove Client</Button>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            clients.Add(new Client() { Name = "Client 1" });
            clients.Add(new Client() { Name = "Client 2" });

            //UpdateCommand = new ClientUpdateCommand(this);
            UpdateCommand = new DelegateCommand(param => ClientExecuteCommand((string)param), param => ClientCanExecuteCommand((string)param));
        }

        public void ClientExecuteCommand(string param)
        {
            ClientDialog cd;
            switch(param)
            {
                case "Add":
                    cd = new ClientDialog("Add Client", "Add Client", "Random User");
                    cd.ShowDialog();
                    clients.Add(new Client() { Name = cd.nameTxtBox.Text });
                    break;
                case "Change":
                    cd = new ClientDialog("Change Client", "Change Client", SelectedClient.Name);
                    cd.ShowDialog();
                    SelectedClient.Name = cd.nameTxtBox.Text;
                    break; 
                case "Remove":
                    clients.Remove(SelectedClient);
                    break;
            }
        }

        public bool ClientCanExecuteCommand(string param)
        {
            if (param == "Add")
                return true;
            else
                return !(SelectedClient == null);
        }
```

I just want to know if that is bad programming practice or if I should create a different command for each button? If this is OK; When should I **NOT** create CommandParameter's?

Thanks in advance for your answers :)

Comment: Really, you should think about designing your command around how it makes sense, not by what needs it. In this case you have an Add, Change, and Remove tag that all effect SelectedClient. Since you are affecting the same context in different ways, I would say this is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @Xcalibur37 That's what I was thinking. Thanks for the feedback :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is *questionable* practice at best. Ask yourself: if you were creating methods instead of commands, would you name them "Update" and pass what to update as a "string param", or would you rather have separate methods with meaningful names?

Your public interface becomes less clear (you need to document what to pass as "param"), you make your design more fragile (a typo will not result in any errors or warnings), you introduce magic constants. Overall, you make your code worse. But a bit shorter, if this is what you're after.

If you want to avoid creating commands for each operation (which can get verbose and thus annoying), you can just use MVVM library which does not force you to. For example, with Caliburn.Micro, you could have just three methods and three buttons, without need to mess with commands and parameters.

Comment: @CodingMadeEasy This is perfectly fine. If the number of methods becomes an issue, you can separate your class into several classes (using aggregation probably). For example, you can put client operations into ClientViewModel instead of putting everything into MainWindowViewModel.

Comment: Thanks so much for the insight :). It's greatly appreciated and I'll be sure to check out Caliburn.Micro

Comment: @CodingMadeEasy If you find an answer useful, you should upvote and/or accept it. You've posted 20 questions already, but has only accepted one answer. I think you're forgetting something. You should visit [your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1772419/codingmadeeasy?tab=questions) and make sure you've upvoted and accepted all appropriate answers.

Comment: Thanks for that. I have upvoted your answer and I will do so on my other questions in a moment. I do have one more question though. Are there added benefits to using aggregation over composition in this scenario? Also how would you implement aggregation in this scenario?

Comment: @CodingMadeEasy Aggregation vs composition is a question of what owns what. In this case, it doesn't really matter what you choose.

Comment: That's what I figured but I had to be sure. Thanks for being so awesome xD